# Public bus from Salta to Los Castillos

Tags: public-transport, argentina, south-america

I plan to do a day trip from Salta to Los Castillos, not a big fan of the wine, so I don't really want to go further to Cafeyate town.
As far as I see, there are several buses from Salta to Cafeyate and takes about 4 hour. Since Los Catillos is on the route 68, it it possible that I jump on one of the buses from Salta to Cafeyate and tell the drive to drop me in Los Castillos?

Is it possible in Argentina and can I catch  bus to get back to Salta from Los Castillos afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get a ticket from Salta to Los Castillos and back.
Although, you should check with the bus operator first.

Alternatively, you could get a day tour of Los Castillos, and Quebrada de las conchas from Cafayate.

There's a lot more to Cafayate than wine. It's an idyllic little town, ideal for walks and good food. 
There is a local goat cheese factory that do free tours in Cafayate, and it is amusing if nothing else.

Have you considered visiting Las Ruinas de Quilmes?

All the best!